# How can I convert 1 dimensional array into 2 dimensional array based on certain key in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My code in javascript like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = {
        "0": {
            "parent_category_id": "1",
            "parent_category_name": "Asia",
            "id": "4",
            "name": "Japan"
        },
        "1": {
            "parent_category_id": "1",
            "parent_category_name": "Asia",
            "id": "5",
            "name": "Korea"
        },
        "2": {
            "parent_category_id": "1",
            "parent_category_name": "Asia",
            "id": "6",
            "name": "Arab"
        },
        "3": {
            "parent_category_id": "2",
            "parent_category_name": "Europa",
            "id": "7",
            "name": "England"
        },
        "4": {
            "parent_category_id": "2",
            "parent_category_name": "Europa",
            "id": "8",
            "name": "Spain"
        },
        "5": {
            "parent_category_id": "2",
            "parent_category_name": "Europa",
            "id": "9",
            "name": "Italy"
        },
        "6": {
            "parent_category_id": "3",
            "parent_category_name": "America",
            "id": "10",
            "name": "Brazil"
        },
        "7": {
            "parent_category_id": "3",
            "parent_category_name": "America",
            "id": "11",
            "name": "Argentina"
        },
        "8": {
            "parent_category_id": "3",
            "parent_category_name": "America",
            "id": "12",
            "name": "Mexico"
        },
    };
    console.log(test);

</script>
```

From the code :

parent_category_id = 1, 2, 3

parent_category_name = asia, europa, america

id = 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11

name = japan, korea, arab, england, spain, italy, brazil, argentina, mexico

I want to display like this :

```
asia
   japan
   korea
   arab
europa
   england
   spain
   italy
america
   brazil
   argentina
   mexico
```

So I need to convert array one dimensional to be array two dimensional to display like that

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a hash table as reference to the categories.

Then iterate the data and assign the values to the same category by checking if the hash table has the specified `id`. If not create a new category and push the node to the result set.

For the output, you could create some nodes which reflects the nested order of each item.

```js
function output(array, parent) {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    parent.appendChild(ul);
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        ul.appendChild(li);
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a.name));
        if (a.children && a.children.length) {
            output(a.children, li);
        }
    });
}

var data = { 0: { parent_category_id: "1", parent_category_name: "Asia", id: "4", name: "Japan" }, 1: { parent_category_id: "1", parent_category_name: "Asia", id: "5", name: "Korea" }, 2: { parent_category_id: "1", parent_category_name: "Asia", id: "6", name: "Arab" }, 3: { parent_category_id: "2", parent_category_name: "Europa", id: "7", name: "England" }, 4: { parent_category_id: "2", parent_category_name: "Europa", id: "8", name: "Spain" }, 5: { parent_category_id: "2", parent_category_name: "Europa", id: "9", name: "Italy" }, 6: { parent_category_id: "3", parent_category_name: "America", id: "10", name: "Brazil" }, 7: { parent_category_id: "3", parent_category_name: "America", id: "11", name: "Argentina" }, 8: { parent_category_id: "3", parent_category_name: "America", id: "12", name: "Mexico" } },
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [];

Object.keys(data).forEach(function (k) {
    if (!hash[data[k].parent_category_id]) {
        hash[data[k].parent_category_id] = { id: data[k].parent_category_id, name: data[k].parent_category_name, children: [] };
        result.push(hash[data[k].parent_category_id]);
    }
    hash[data[k].parent_category_id].children.push({ id: data[k].id, name: data[k].name });
});

console.log(result);

output(result, document.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Countries should be an array since it doesn't have a relevant key.

```js
var test = {
        "0": {
            "parent_category_id": "1",
            "parent_category_name": "Asia",
            "id": "4",
            "name": "Japan"
        },
        "1": {
            "parent_category_id": "1",
            "parent_category_name": "Asia",
            "id": "5",
            "name": "Korea"
        },
        "2": {
            "parent_category_id": "1",
            "parent_category_name": "Asia",
            "id": "6",
            "name": "Arab"
        },
        "3": {
            "parent_category_id": "2",
            "parent_category_name": "Europa",
            "id": "7",
            "name": "England"
        },
        "4": {
            "parent_category_id": "2",
            "parent_category_name": "Europa",
            "id": "8",
            "name": "Spain"
        },
        "5": {
            "parent_category_id": "2",
            "parent_category_name": "Europa",
            "id": "9",
            "name": "Italy"
        },
        "6": {
            "parent_category_id": "3",
            "parent_category_name": "America",
            "id": "10",
            "name": "Brazil"
        },
        "7": {
            "parent_category_id": "3",
            "parent_category_name": "America",
            "id": "11",
            "name": "Argentina"
        },
        "8": {
            "parent_category_id": "3",
            "parent_category_name": "America",
            "id": "12",
            "name": "Mexico"
        }
};
   
var _formatted = {};

for(obj in test){
     
    var region = test[obj].parent_category_name;
    if(typeof _formatted[region] === "undefined"){
        _formatted[region] = [];
    }    
    _formatted[region].push(test[obj].name);
}

console.log(_formatted);
```